# Oauth1.0 API issue with Python

Tags: python, oauth

I'm trying to get magiccardmarket.eu API authentication to work in Python, but no matter whether I'm using rauth or requests_oauthlib, I get 403.

My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import logging

import rauth
import requests_oauthlib

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

mkm_app_token = 'B7VI9Qg2xh855WtR'
mkm_app_secret = '<cut>'
mkm_access_token = 'LQj2rUwOFUJsmuJvCTlny1UzGZSXzHjo'
mkm_token_secret = '<cut>'

url = 'https://sandbox.mkmapi.eu/ws/v1.1/account'

# session = rauth.OAuth1Session(
#   consumer_key=mkm_app_token,
#   consumer_secret=mkm_app_secret,
#   access_token=mkm_access_token,
#   access_token_secret=mkm_token_secret,
# )

session = requests_oauthlib.OAuth1Session(
    mkm_app_token,
    client_secret=mkm_app_secret,
    resource_owner_key=mkm_access_token,
    resource_owner_secret=mkm_token_secret,
)

r = session.get(url)
print(r)
```

When I look at debugging info, everything seems fine (of course besides 403 response):

```
DEBUG:requests_oauthlib.oauth1_auth:Signing request <PreparedRequest [GET]> using client <Client nonce=None, signature_method=HMAC-SHA1, realm=None, encoding=utf-8, timestamp=None, resource_owner_secret=****, decoding=utf-8, verifier=None, signature_type=AUTH_HEADER, rsa_key=None, resource_owner_key=LQj2rUwOFUJsmuJvCTlny1UzGZSXzHjo, client_secret=****, callback_uri=None, client_key=B7VI9Qg2xh855WtR>
DEBUG:requests_oauthlib.oauth1_auth:Including body in call to sign: False
DEBUG:oauthlib.oauth1.rfc5849:Collected params: [(u'oauth_nonce', u'87129670621454425921416648590'), (u'oauth_timestamp', u'1416648590'), (u'oauth_consumer_key', u'B7VI9Qg2xh855WtR'), (u'oauth_signature_method', u'HMAC-SHA1'), (u'oauth_version', u'1.0'), (u'oauth_token', u'LQj2rUwOFUJsmuJvCTlny1UzGZSXzHjo')]
DEBUG:oauthlib.oauth1.rfc5849:Normalized params: oauth_consumer_key=B7VI9Qg2xh855WtR&oauth_nonce=87129670621454425921416648590&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1416648590&oauth_token=LQj2rUwOFUJsmuJvCTlny1UzGZSXzHjo&oauth_version=1.0
DEBUG:oauthlib.oauth1.rfc5849:Normalized URI: https://sandbox.mkmapi.eu/ws/v1.1/account
DEBUG:oauthlib.oauth1.rfc5849:Base signing string: GET&https%3A%2F%2Fsandbox.mkmapi.eu%2Fws%2Fv1.1%2Faccount&oauth_consumer_key%3DB7VI9Qg2xh855WtR%26oauth_nonce%3D87129670621454425921416648590%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1416648590%26oauth_token%3DLQj2rUwOFUJsmuJvCTlny1UzGZSXzHjo%26oauth_version%3D1.0
DEBUG:oauthlib.oauth1.rfc5849:Signature: 291LTesHZR6W4bjZ1NqSW5hEgoM=
DEBUG:oauthlib.oauth1.rfc5849:Encoding URI, headers and body to utf-8.
DEBUG:requests_oauthlib.oauth1_auth:Updated url: https://sandbox.mkmapi.eu/ws/v1.1/account
DEBUG:requests_oauthlib.oauth1_auth:Updated headers: {'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Authorization': 'OAuth oauth_nonce="87129670621454425921416648590", oauth_timestamp="1416648590", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_consumer_key="B7VI9Qg2xh855WtR", oauth_token="LQj2rUwOFUJsmuJvCTlny1UzGZSXzHjo", oauth_signature="291LTesHZR6W4bjZ1NqSW5hEgoM%3D"', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.4.3 CPython/2.7.8 Darwin/14.0.0'}
DEBUG:requests_oauthlib.oauth1_auth:Updated body: None
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): sandbox.mkmapi.eu
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /ws/v1.1/account HTTP/1.1" 403 None
```

This is not an issue of authentication details, which are provided on account profile page when you request dedicated application API access, since those details work fine with PHP example provided by the site: https://www.mkmapi.eu/ws/documentation/API:Auth_libcurl

When I go through site's documentation, nothing seems out of ordinary: https://www.mkmapi.eu/ws/documentation/API:Auth_Overview

I honestly don't know where to go from here...

Comment: I seems like you are not using an OAuth Header, as described in https://www.mkmapi.eu/ws/documentation/API:Auth_OAuthHeader - I'm also trying to translate my old py-script to the new API and starting to work on that.

Comment: I believe those are handled by OAuth1Session and visible in the 3rd debug line, unless I'm missing something. Please do let me know if you manage to progress with that, I ended up abandoning the project...

Comment: Running into the same exact issue -- my app works fine from C#, but I can't seem to get the authentication to work from Python.

Comment: @MateuszM. You are right - when I posted my comment I didn't fully realize to which extend OAuth1Session is handling things. However, I couldn't manage to produce it the header I wanted, namely the signature was a different one than the one in the header documentation (when using the infos provided there) https://www.mkmapi.eu/ws/documentation/API:Auth_OAuthHeader for this reason I decided to build my own header generator with [black jack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGi6Q1pNbS0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realized that the code above with `requests_oauthlib` didn't build the header like it was layed out in the documentation, so I ended up inventing the wheel again and building the header myself, following the steps outlined in the documentation: https://www.mkmapi.eu/ws/documentation/API:Auth_OAuthHeader

The following script is not very beautiful, but it does its job.

```
import requests
from urllib import quote_plus as rawurlencode
import time
import string
import random
import operator
from hashlib import sha1
from hmac import new as hmac


def id_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

# personal Info - taken from https://www.mkmapi.eu/ws/documentation/API:Auth_Overview
mkmAppToken = 'bfaD9xOU0SXBhtBP'
mkmAppSecret = 'pChvrpp6AEOEwxBIIUBOvWcRG3X9xL4Y'
mkmAccessToken = 'lBY1xptUJ7ZJSK01x4fNwzw8kAe5b10Q'
mkmAccessSecret = 'hc1wJAOX02pGGJK2uAv1ZOiwS7I9Tpoe'

# Url to access on mkm
# note that this deviates from the example in the header documentation (https://www.mkmapi.eu/ws/documentation/API:Auth_OAuthHeader) which uses
#accessUrl = 'https://www.mkmapi.eu/ws/v1.1/account'
accessUrl = 'https://www.mkmapi.eu/ws/v1.1/output.json/account'

#Method for access

MyMethod = "GET"

baseString = MyMethod + "&" + rawurlencode(accessUrl) + "&"

# create a random string
# the documentation in https://www.mkmapi.eu/ws/documentation/API:Auth_OAuthHeader uses
#nonce = 53eb1f44909d6
nonce = id_generator(8)

# what time is it?
# the documentation in https://www.mkmapi.eu/ws/documentation/API:Auth_OAuthHeader uses
#now = 1407917892

now = str(int(time.time()))

MyOauthmethod = "HMAC-SHA1"
MyOauthver = "1.0"

# define Parameters and values, order doesn't matter
paramDict ={"oauth_consumer_key":mkmAppToken, "oauth_token" :mkmAccessToken, "oauth_nonce":nonce, "oauth_timestamp":now, "oauth_signature_method":MyOauthmethod, "oauth_version":MyOauthver}

# sorting of parameters is done here
sorted_paramDict = sorted(paramDict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))

#collect the full parameters string
paramStr = ''

for kv in sorted_paramDict:
    paramStr = paramStr + kv[0] + "=" + kv[1] + "&"


# and get rid of the trailing ampersand
paramStr = paramStr[:-1]


#concatenate request and oauth parameters
baseString = baseString + rawurlencode(paramStr)

# concatenate both keys
signingKey = rawurlencode(mkmAppSecret) + "&" + rawurlencode(mkmAccessSecret)
# and create a hased signature with the key and the baseString
Signature = hmac(signingKey, baseString, sha1).digest().encode('base64')[:-1]


# construct the header from the parameters and the URL and the signature
MyHeader = 'OAuth ' + 'realm="' + accessUrl + '", ' 

for kv in sorted_paramDict:
    MyHeader += kv[0] + '="' + kv[1] + '",'

MyHeader += 'oauth_signature="' + Signature +'"'

headers = {'Authorization': MyHeader}

# and now requests can do its magic (pun intended)

r = requests.get(accessUrl, headers=headers)

outjson = r.json()
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide the realm as an argument to the OAuth1Session, like so:

```
session = requests_oauthlib.OAuth1Session(
    mkm_app_token,
    client_secret=mkm_app_secret,
    resource_owner_key=mkm_access_token,
    resource_owner_secret=mkm_token_secret,
    realm=url
)
```

Other things I have run into in the past include the fact that the mkm api doesn't (or at least didn't) accept URI-escaped parameters, so you may need to unescape them.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who's reading in 2020, there's no need to reinvent the wheel, just pass the Oauth header and the parameters to requests, here's an example with metaproducts/find:

```
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
import json 
import passwords

card_name = 'Tarmogoyf'

output = 'output.json'
base_url = 'https://api.cardmarket.com/ws/v2.0/' + output + '/'

url = base_url + 'metaproducts/find'
params={'search': card_name}

headeroauth = OAuth1(
    realm = url,
    client_key = passwords.mkm_app_token,
    client_secret = passwords.mkm_app_secret,
    resource_owner_key = passwords.mkm_access_token,
    resource_owner_secret = passwords.mkm_token_secret,
)

response = requests.get(
    url,
    params,
    auth = headeroauth
    )


if (response.ok == True):
    json_response = response.json()
    print(json.dumps(json_response, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
else:
    print(str(response.status_code) + " " + response.reason)
    exit()
```

The /output.json/ part of the string makes the output JSON instead of XML

Comment: I've been trying that and all answers on the page, I always get a 403. Does that still work for you?