# Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth, typeerror, hmac

I've been trying to make an app to interact with MKM's API and I've decided to not use the OAuth1 library and make the headers by myself and I'm having problems with the signature that Oauth1 needs. The entire process (for php) can be found [here](https://api.cardmarket.com/ws/documentation/API:Auth_OAuthHeader).

This is the code that I have as of right now (I was testing the API by trying to send a single request, just so I could see how it works)

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests
from urllib.parse import quote_plus as rawurlencode
import time
import string
import random
import operator
import uuid
from hashlib import sha1
from hmac import new as hmac


#check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27075944/oauth1-0-api-issue-with-python/32510649
def main():


    app_token = "XXXXXXXXX"
    app_secret = "XXXXXXXXX"
    access_token = "XXXXXXXXX"
    access_token_secret = "XXXXXXXXX"

    signing_key = str(app_secret+'&'+access_token_secret)

    nonce = uuid.uuid4().hex

    url = 'https://api.cardmarket.com/ws/v2.0/account'
    base_url='GET&'+rawurlencode(url)+'&'
    params = 'oauth_consumer_key=XXXXXXXXX&'+ \
    'oauth_nonce='+nonce+'&'+\
    'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1&'+\
    'oauth_timestamp='+str(int(time.time()))+'&'+\
    'oauth_token=XXXXXXXXX&'+\
    'oauth_version=1.0'
    base_string = rawurlencode(params)
    string_f = base_url+base_string
    signature = hmac(signing_key.encode('utf-8'), base_string, sha1).digest().encode('base64')[:-1]
    MyHeader = 'OAuth ' + 'realm="' + url + '", ' 
    MyHeader += 'oauth_consumer_key' + '="' + 'XXXXXXXXX' + '",'
    MyHeader += 'oauth_nonce' + '="' + nonce + '",'
    MyHeader += 'oauth_signature_method' + '="' + 'HMAC-SHA1' + '",'
    MyHeader += 'oauth_timestamp' + '="' + str(int(time.time())) + '",'
    MyHeader += 'oauth_token' + '="' + 'XXXXXXXXX' + '",'
    MyHeader += 'oauth_version' + '="' + '1.0' + '",'
    MyHeader += 'oauth_signature="' + signature +'"'

    headers = {'Authorization': MyHeader}


    response = request.get(url,headers=headers)

    print(response.json())
    #print(base_string+"\n\n")
    #print("KEY "+signing_key+"\n\n")
    #print("String final "+string_f+"\n\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I use the script, I get the next message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "origin.py", line 58, in <module>
    main()
  File "origin.py", line 36, in main
    signature = hmac(signing_key.encode('utf-8'), base_string, sha1).digest().encode('base64')[:-1]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/hmac.py", line 144, in new
    return HMAC(key, msg, digestmod)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/hmac.py", line 84, in __init__
    self.update(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/hmac.py", line 93, in update
    self.inner.update(msg)
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

Now, I've been investigating about this and I've tried different methods on the HMAC constructor so it wouldn't fail, I've even separated the constructor and the digest() so I could pinpoint more exactly where the error was. With this said, I've run out of ideas, I've read like 100 different posts about this specific TypeError and I really don't know what to do anymore, It's probably going to be a really stupid thing but I really need your help guys, I'm kinda losing my mind to be honest :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode your `base_string` as hmac is using bytes, not unicode string:

```
signature = hmac(signing_key.encode('utf-8'), base_string.encode(), sha1)
```